# LDP user search filter not shsowing all users

Tags: active-directory

Im trying to serach all users in a specific group in Active directory using LDAP. but not all the users from the group is not showing in the result. 
but if i specifically serach sam account name, i can se the missing user.

your advice is appreciated

Joseph

Comment: IIRC, this is because AD returns only 1000 records per request, and you should do multiple request to retrieve subsequent records.

Comment: For example, read [this article](http://forums.asp.net/p/1309400/2574771.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Yasir .il check and get back to you

Comment: Thank you Yasir. you are correct AD returns only 1000 records per request. we created morethan 1000 users and tested. Once again thank you for your valuable comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably provide some more information.

What Forest and Domain Levels
code being used
how many group members are being returned

My GUESS is that your issue is related to the limit of 1,500 (W3k) as discussed in http://itq.nl/blogs/post/Get-more-than-1500-members-from-an-Active-Directory-group.aspx

-jim

Comment: Thanx Jim. this i'll try and get back to you(even we are using Win2008 not W3k)  in 2008 also have limit of 1500?

Comment: Thnx JIm. issue resolved. you are correct the issue was the limit of 1000 as you mentioned